# Panda not matching two different columns information together

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image: The image is of my spreadsheet]

I'm having an issue with Panda where its prints the whole date frame multiple times, causing it to slow down and along with that, it prints out the incorrect information when being requested to print out 1 specific item

I'm trying to get 'ETA' to print along with the Customer Names in the same order. I have a Excel Spreadsheet but am unable to match the requested name with the requested ETA. I.e. `"WILLIAM KLEIN"  "10/12/21" "ROGER FRY" "10/13/21"` is what I want. What I get is `"WILLIAM KLEIN"  "10/12/21" "ROGER FRY" "10/12/21"` Ect ect, until the next iteration `"WILLIAM KLEIN"  "10/13/21" "ROGER FRY" "10/13/21"`

```
import pandas as pd

desired_width = 500

workbook = pd.read_excel('jobs2.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")  # Set up for the excel sheet

# region Setting Console Boundaries
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)
# endregion

# Setting Value for two weeks out if job is more than two weeks out.
twoWeeksOuts = "25,8,2021"

# Getting information from the Excel Sheet
customerName = workbook["Customer Name"]
eta = workbook["ETA"]


for x in eta:
    print("PROACTIVE CONTACT TASK: Called " + customerName + " to advise of ETA of product for " + x.strftime("%b %d %Y") + " and that we are still on schedule. Advised Independent PROvider will contact them within two business days of when product is available for installation.")
```

It prints out 100's of iterations of the same information just with the date changed to match that iteration, which is not by design. I can't even post an example because its so many iterations of different names, same dates. Please assist!

Comment: `customerName` does not change within the loop.  It has a fixed value, and the whole workbook will get printed each time.  What were you expecting here?  Did you expect `customerName` to be a single name?  Was it supposed to come from the `eta` df?

Comment: Customer name gets applied no issue. I was expecting to get the list of names, with the list of ETA's matching with the name on the same row. How would I go about just getting one of those names and its matching eta's and through looping getting the rest of the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to get the info from sheet directly to the `print()` function, had the sheet move the information to two separate arrays. One for each workbook column:

```
# Generate workbooks for Customer Name and ETA
customerName = workbook["Customer Name"] 
eta = workbook["ETA"]

# Array creation for storing from both types 
customerNameArr = [""]
etaArr= [""]

# For each item in range of 85(Size of Sheet) append to previously created arrays
# 0+X to get rid of blank values created by arrays
for x in range(85):
    customerNameArr.append(customerName.iloc[0+x]) 

for x in range(85):
    etaArr.append(eta.iloc[0+x])

for x in range(85):
    print(customerNameArr[0+x]+" "+str(etaArr[0+x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two different variables 'Customer Name' and 'eta' separately use in one :

```
eta = workbook["ETA", "Customer Name"]

for x in eta:
    print("PROACTIVE CONTACT TASK: Called " + x[1]+ " to advise of ETA of 
    product for " + x[0].strftime("%b %d %Y") + " and that we are still on 
    schedule. Advised Independent Provider will contact them within two 
    business days of when product is available for installation.")
```

hope it will work for u

Comment: Unfortunately raises a key error when ran that way, thank you for the answer though!

Comment: Does it work with `x["Customer Name"]` instead of `x[1]` and `x['ETA']` instead of `x[0]`?

Comment: @AJBiffl nope, still throws a key error, even with the variables being in the print function.

Comment: Sorry, which line is throwing the key error? Can you make `eta`, or is it during the loop?

Comment: Oh hold up by default you iterate through the *columns* of the dataframe, not the rows... use `for x in eta.values:` to iterate through the rows but leave everything else @Subhamrawat suggested unchanged

Answer (score 1):

try iterrows()...

```
for RowIndex , Row in workbook.iterrows() :
    print(
        "PROACTIVE CONTACT TASK: Called " +
        Row["customerName"] +
        " to advise of ETA of product for " +
        x.strftime("%b %d %Y") +
        " and that we are still on schedule. Advised Independent PROvider will contact them within two business days of when product is available for installation."
        )
```

and with it i think you can skip :

```
# Getting information from the Excel Sheet
customerName = workbook["Customer Name"]
eta = workbook["ETA"]
```

i would type the strftime differently though but with the above i think you can work it out---